# only property-list objects (NSNumber) in NSDictionary but not able to store dict in UserDefaults

Tags: nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults, nsnumber

I have an NSDictionary with NSNumbers as Values and Keys. These numbers represent certain settings in the app and I would like to store the dictionary in UserDefaults. Since NSNumbers are a property-list object, i thought this should work, but i retrieve the following error:

`*** -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '{
    2 = 1;
}' of class '__NSDictionaryM'.  Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values.`

The (simplified) test-code I use is:

```
NSNumber *one = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
NSNumber *two = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
NSDictionary *defaultSetting = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: one, two, nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:defaultSetting forKey:@"settings"];
```

Why doesn't this work? I do not see what's wrong with it?

Thanks for your time and replies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your dictionary must be like this:

```
NSDictionary *defaultSetting = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                         one, @"one", 
                                                         two, @"two", 
                                                         nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. In my case the number '2' is the key for number '1' (its a #defined value). But the UserDefaults does not seem to like to have an NSNUmber as a key value? (i use it throughout the app successfully). If I convert the key to an string is works.. ?

Comment: Keys must be NSString, not another data type.

Comment: Interesting.. i checked the NSDictionary documentation and you are indeed correct. Apple specifies that any object can be an key, but an string is required for key-value coding.. Again, thanks for your response!